# new text in dynamic TextView is invisible if previous text was scrolled

Tags: android, scroll, textview

Im dynamicaly loading text into TextView with scrollbar enabled, but when text is longer and I scroll down and load new (shorter) text into TextView,new text is invisible, because view is scrolled down and there is no scroller shown because new text is short.
Is there any function to reset scroll position, or automaticaly scroll up, what I can call before load new data? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textview.scrollTo(0,0)` solved it, i must overlook this in api :)